# Sublime Text 2: Recognize Makefile.local as a Makefile

Tags: sublimetext2

How do I configure Sublime Text 2 so that it recognizes a file named `Makefile.local` as a Makefile, so I don't have to manually do "Set Syntax: Makefile" when I open this file?

Comment: If you want it for all .local files, open one then click view, syntax & use "open all with current extension" from the top of the menu

Comment: @AlexK. Is it possible to just match "Makefile.local" or, even better, "Makefile.*"?

Comment: This plugin https://github.com/phillipkoebbe/DetectSyntax can match syntax against a filename regexp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the tag `<string>Makefile.local</string>` to the `<array>` section in **`Makefile.tmLanguage`** file.

```xml
<dict>
    <key>fileTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>Makefile.local</string>
        <string>GNUmakefile</string>
        <string>makefile</string>
        <string>Makefile</string>
        <string>OCamlMakefile</string>
        <string>make</string>
    </array>
    <key>name</key>
...
```

To find the file, click on `Preferences | Browse Packages...` menu.

The file can be used to change more [Syntax Definition](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html) options.

Comment: Make sure to save a new version of this file in your User preference folder. This will retain it through updates.

Answer (score 2):

You can turn on syntax highlighting based on the contents of the file.

For example, I have numerous makefiles named `Makefile.msp430` and similar, having the first line as follows:

```
#-*-Makefile-*- vim:syntax=make
```

This is typical practice for other editors such as vim.

However, for this to work you need to modify the 
`Makefile.tmLanguage` file.

1. Find the file (for Sublime Text 3 in Ubuntu) at:

   ```
   /opt/sublime_text/Packages/Makefile.sublime-package
   ```

Note, that is really a zip file. Copy it, rename with .zip at the end, and extract the Makefile.tmLanguage file from it.

2. Edit the new `Makefile.tmLanguage` by adding the "firstLineMatch" key and string after the "fileTypes" section. In the example below, the last two lines are new (should be added by you). The `<string>` section holds the regular expression, that will enable syntax highlighting for the files that match the first line. This expression recognizes two patterns: "`#-*-Makefile-*-`" and "`vim:syntax=make`", but you can improve it.

   ```
   <key>fileTypes</key>
   <array>
       <string>GNUmakefile</string>
       <string>makefile</string>
       <string>Makefile</string>
       <string>OCamlMakefile</string>
       <string>make</string>
   </array>

   <key>firstLineMatch</key>
   <string>^#\s*-\*-Makefile-\*-|^#.*\s*vim:syntax=make</string>
   ```
3. Place the new `Makefile.tmLanguage` in the User settings directory:

   ```
   ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Makefile.tmLanguage
   ```

From now on, the files matching the first line rules should turn on the syntax highlighting.